# HTML Urls - how to append to the existing url

Tags: url, append, hyperlink

This is a stupidly easy question, however after searching for a long time I have yet to yield any results.

My question is as follows.

I have a webpage with the url http://domain.com/mypage/ladeda/

I have a link on this page.

```
<a href="/1/">Page 1</a>
```

That link sends me to http://domain.com/1/

```
<a href="1/">Page 1</a>
```

That link takes me to http://domain.com/mypage/1/

How do i get my link to take me to http://domain.com/mypage/ladeda/1/

without having to extract all the aspects of the page url and put them within the href.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<base href="/mypage/ladeda/" />
...
<a href="1/">(goes to http://domain.com/mypage/ladeda/1/)</a>
```

Via the [`<base>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4).

---

**But!**
`<a href="1/">Page 1</a>` *should* take you to `http://domain.com/mypage/ladeda/1/` already *provided* that (a) you don't use a `<base>` element already *and* (b) the current resource is really `http://domain.com/mypage/ladeda/` (with a trailing slash).

Comment: The missing trailing slash was my mistake. I wasn't aware of this. This should get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="/mypage/ladeda/1">Page 1</a>
```

If the current page isn't in the same directory (real or virtual) as the target page, you're going to have to specify a complete path. Either relative, or absolute. There's no way around it.

Comment: I did specify "without having to extract all the aspects of the page url and put them within the href." Thanks

Comment: If the current page isn't in the same directory (real or virtual) as the target page, you're going to have to specify a complete path. Either relative, or absolute. There's no way around it.

Comment: @MarcB there is no way around it